# List of cubical spaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Suppose I have a three-dimensional cube (I tend to think of it as a regular ideal cube in $\mathbb{H}^3,$ but you don't have to). I glue up its sides in some way to obtain topological spaces. The question is: has someone made a list of such? (if you think of it as an ideal cube, then the vertices, or their images after gluing, are not really in the glued up object). How many of these are manifolds/orbifolds (again, I am interested in both cases with and without punctures at the vertices).

Comment: "Sides" means $2$-dimensional faces? "In some way" means some pairing of the faces with some orientation or some more arbitrary thing?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, sides means "2-dimensional faces", and the "in some way", means identifying faces in pair (I did not say that I wanted the quotient to be orientable -- I do, but obviously non-orientable guys are of interest as well).

Comment: Some appear in this paper: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1231694

Comment: Sorry, I meant here: http://books.google.com/books?id=WrKfdUgvtWIC&lpg=PA17&ots=Fa6Xnvz4mA&dq=aitchison%20rubinstein%20platonic&lr&pg=PA22#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: It has been done for the octahedron in the orientable case: http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1429 but I think there is no complete list for the cube.

Comment: It's been done for all the platonic solids in the case you want a manifold quotient: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0104182.

Comment: @RyanBudney Ah, that's a great reference, thanks! (even if it does not quite answer the question...)